# Update dropdown selection with JQuery in Java Play Framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, playframework

I want to dynamically add field inputs to a form as the user completes it.  However, if the user changes a value for a previous field that others depended on, then I want to hide those later fields again and reset their values back to the default.  I can show and hide the input fields without a problem.  However, no matter what I do, I cannot change the value of the selection dropdown menu.

Here is my script:

```
$(function() {
    $('#type_selection').change(function() {
        var case_type = $('#type_selection :selected').val();
        if(case_type !== "") {  //the default value is an empty string
           $('.subtype-panel').slideDown('slow');
        }
        else {
            $('.subtype-panel').slideUp('slow');
            $('#subytype_selection').val("").change();  
        }
    });

});
```

Play template:

```
@(caseForm: play.data.Form[Case])

@import views.html.common._
@import models._


@implicitFieldConstructor = @{
    b3.vertical.fieldConstructor
}

@main("New Case Info") {
    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>New Case Information<span class="pull-right label label-primary">Open</span></h3>
    </div>

    <fieldset>
    @b3.form(action = routes.CaseController.save()) {

        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">Case Type</div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    @b3.select(caseForm("caseType"),
                        options = options(Case.typeOptions),
                        '_id -> "type_selection",
                        '_label -> "Case Type",
                        '_default -> "-- Select a Type --")
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    @datePicker(caseForm("date"), '_label -> "Date", 'placeholder -> "mm/dd/yyyy")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-primary subtype-panel">
            <div class="panel-heading">Case Subtype</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                    @b3.select(caseForm("caseSubType"),
                        options = options(Case.subTypeOptions),
                        '_id -> "subtype_selection",
                        '_label -> "Subtype",
                        '_default -> "-- Select a Subtype --")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    }

    </fieldset>

}
```

The b3 syntax may look a bit odd to you.  It comes from a play bootstrap library: http://adrianhurt.github.io/play-bootstrap/
For b3 select fields, the default option is automatically assigned a value of an empty string.  This is what I want to change my selection choice back to using JQuery.

Comment: Did you inspected the generated `id` by `b3`? I think if you want the override it, you should use: `'id -> "type_selection"`, so without the underscore

Comment: @adis That worked!  I was not aware of that rule with b3.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as adis said in his comment.  Using `_id -> foo` changes the id of the entire form-group (the label and the dropdown), but it does not change the id of the selection box specifically.  You have to use `id -> foo` to do that.